# Image located on UIElement is not showing [WPF]

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm creating `"Custom Control"` i put image in `"Themes"` folder, lets call it `image.jpg`, in `Generic.xaml` of the `"Custom Control"`, i wrote this:

```
<Button Width="30" Height="30">
    <Image Source="image.jpg" Width="20" Height="20"/>
</Button>
```

I recompiled the project, and when i used it in other project, Button is shown, but the image isn't... what i am doing wrong... Also the image is set as Resource in its properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  should  locate correctly  your image 
Something  like this

```
<Button Width="30" Height="30">
<Image Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/image.jpg" Width="20" Height="20"/>
</Button>
```